# MarshalError: Unable to marshal response: JSONDecodeError AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have written a `lambda` function in AWS which fetches the data from Dynamo DB and return in JSON format. It take a request input body in a format - `{"Datestamp":"2021-01-11"}` and return reports for this date.

I am calling this from a web page using java script but I am getting ``unable to marshal response``` error.

Javascript Code -

```
$.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    contentType : "application/json",
                    url : "https://mypoc-app.com/api/",
                    data: 
                    { 
                        "Datestamp" : "2021-02-15"
                    },
                     headers: {
                         'Authorization': 'Basic',
                         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                         'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS',
                         'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : true
                         //'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
                         },
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(data,status) {
                        console.log("Date format is " + data);
        
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                            
                                drawTable(response.data);
                        }
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Error");
                    }
                    
                });
```

Lambda function -

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        result = []
        queryresponse = resultstable.scan()
        for i in queryresponse['Items']:
            result.append(i['reports'])
        block=['{"type": "section","text": {"type": "mrkdwn","text": "*Found below reports using Datestamp provided*"}}']
        for item in result:
            print(event["body"])
            body = json.loads(event["body"])
            if item.find(body['Datestamp']) != -1:
                itema='{"type": "section","text": {"type": "mrkdwn","text": "<https://%s/%s/%s/index.html|%s>"}}' % (URL,Prefix,item,item)
                block.append(itema)
        block=('[{}]'.format(', '.join(block)))
        return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        'body': block,
        "isBase64Encoded": False
    }
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return(e)
```

Error Logs in Cloudwatch -

```
START RequestId: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Version: $LATEST
Datestamp=2021-02-15
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
[ERROR] Runtime.MarshalError: Unable to marshal response: JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)') is not JSON serializable
END XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I believe it has something to do with the way I am passing date in the request or the way lambda is handling it because certainly from the cloud watch logs it doesn't look like it's in a JSON format.

Can someone please provide their expertise in this case as I have already scratched my head around it?

Comment: Can you successfully run this Lambda function from within the Lambda Console?

Comment: @smac2020 yes it works fine from AWS console and even using the postman. I pass the ```datestamp``` in the request body like this - ```{"Datestamp":"2021-01-11"}```

Answer (score 0):

As you said it works fine from the console - i suspect your issue is trying to invoke it using AJAX. The better way would be to use the **AWS SDK for JavaScript**. Use the Lambda Client API to invoke the Lambda function from within a Script tag.

Here is the examples for JS API for Lambda:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javascriptv3/example_code/lambda

To invoke a Lambda function, you can call the invoke operation. See this Java example. Port this example to JS API.

[https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/lambda/src/main/java/com/example/lambda/LambdaInvoke.java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javascriptv3/example_code/lambda)

To pass data, use the **InvokeRequest** object.